# My android App is searchable in Google play ..but when i try to open my app page..getting not found error

Tags: android

I have submitted my first android app in Google play store two hours back..Now in Google play search,my app is visible.When i try to click and open my app page,i am getting not found error "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server." I really got confused..what's the issue..any idea..

Comment: It can take up to 24 hours before your app becomes visible on Google Play. I suggest to just wait a bit longer.

Comment: Hi..my app is visible in google search..but when i try to click that and open my app page to see the description and all..i am getting not found error..